# Comparing search engine configuration - paired or unpaired test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, paired-data

I have trouble of deciding whether I should go for **paired or unpaired test** in my case. Let's say that I need to evaluate the performance of two search engine configurations and check whether the performance of Configuration 2 is better than Configuration 1.

I can either:

- compare the search performance on **two independent** queries samples and test whether the `mean(metric for config 1) > mean(metric for config 2)`
  or
- create **one sample of queries**, pass them through two configuration and compare the means of metrics as well

Is it actually true that I can approach this problem in two different ways ? If that's the case, what are the consequences of going for one option over the other ?

I'd be grateful for any guidance as to how to approach it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paired design has greater statistical power, and should almost always be preferred where feasible. Unpaired designs are often necessary when collecting paired data would be difficult (e.g. it's too much of a time commitment for participants), but it's hard to imagine that's the case here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As far as I see, the paired test also requires smaller minimal sample for a test to be reliable. So am I correct in saying that in order to test my hypothesis correctly, it is more a matter of creating representative sample of queries rather than creating big enough one ?